# DOMDocument xpath query cut off time

Tags: xpath, domdocument, domxpath

is there a way to cut of the query and return back the results.. preset time to take to get all images from the given url ..    i.e. query half of the webpage ? or  job time not greater than 5 seconds, so therefore, it will get everything it can in 5 seconds.....

my xpath code:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $htmlget);
       $nodelist = $xpath->query( "//img/@src" );
```

Comment: done....      any way to stop query time and return back with results within a specific timeframe